# Как из input передать данные в функцию

Tags: input, javascript

```
<input type="text"  id="add_id_user">
<button onClick='return add_del("add_id", "сюда надо содержимое add_id_user")' type="submit" >submit</button>
```

Comment: <button onClick='return add_del("add_id", document.getElementById("add_id_user").value)' type="submit" >submit</button>

Как задам вопрос так сам и отвечаю, всем спасибо :))

Comment: попробуйте `Ractive`, `Vue` или `Angular` - вам понравится. Как ни странно, там ваш код - вполне хорошая практика (только не придётся искать элемент)

Answer (score 3):

передаете вторым параметром id инпута, а потом в функции add_del() делаете выборку по id и вытаскиваете нужные данные

```
<input type="text"  id="add_id_user">
<button onClick='return add_del("add_id", "add_id_user")' type="submit" >submit</button>

function ad_del(id, user_id) {
   var input_val = document.getElementById(user_id).value;
}
```

Comment: да было бы так, или по другому если б я не использовал одну функцию универсально для нескольких действий. Как видите я сам выше ответил на свой вопрос :)

Answer (score 0):

Так ?

html:

```
<input type="text"  id="add_id_user">
<button id="add_button" type="submit" >submit</button>
```

js:

```
(function() {
    var adduser_input=document.getElementById('add_id_user');
    document.getElementById('add_button').addEventListener('click',call_add);
    function call_add() {
        return add_del(adduser_input.value);
    }
})();
```

но вообще я бы рекомендовал не использовать здесь click, лучше submit на форму.

html:

```
<form id="formIdName">
    <input type="text"  id="add_id_user">
    <button type="submit" >submit</button>
</form>
```

js:

```
(function() {
    var adduser_input=document.getElementById('add_id_user');
    document.getElementById('formIdName').addEventListener('submit',call_add);
    function call_add() {
        return add_del(adduser_input.value);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Можно и так, но писать функции для каждого поля это не есть хорошо. так как в add_del передается совсем не два параметра а больше. Это я пример такой короткий привел. На самом деле она принимает 5 - 6 параметров, для каждого input свои.

Comment: ну так написать надо универсальную, вот события в разметке это точно не хорошо.